# How to extend React.Component interface with a "direct" property ?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In a code like this one :

```
interface Props extends React.HTMLAttributes {
  // ...
}

interface State {
  // ...
}

interface TextFieldComponent {
  field: HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement
}

export default class TextField extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  render() {
    const fieldProps = Object.assign({
      ref: (element: HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement) => this.field = element
    }, fieldOtherProps)

    return <input {...fieldProps} />
  }
}
```

I would like to be able to create the `field` property directly on my component since it makes no sense to have it in the state. For now, I obviously have this error :

```
182       ref: (element: HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement) => this.field = element

text-field/index.tsx(182,70): error TS2339: Property 'field' does not exist on type 'TextField'.
```

I guess I need to create a new interface (`TextFieldComponent`) and find a way to extends the `React.Component` one with it but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact I found it, it was quite simple. I just had to declare the class property with the Typescript way :

```
export default class TextField extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  private field: HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement

  render() {
    const fieldProps = Object.assign({
      ref: (element: HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement) => this.field = element
    }, fieldOtherProps)

    return <input {...fieldProps} />
  }
}
```